# shell script parser error double quotes closing even when closed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

```
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash
basedir=$(dirname "$0")

#unset LD_PRELOAD in case termux-exec is installed. If termux-exec is also installed inside the jail it will set again.
unset LD_PRELOAD

command="proot"
command+=" -r $basedir/termux-fs"
command+=" -b /system"
command+=" -b /dev/"
command+=" -b /sys/"
command+=" -b /etc/"
command+=" -b /proc/"
command+=" -b /vendor"
command+=" -b /data/dalvik-cache/"
command+=" -b /property_contexts"
if [ -n "$(ls -A "$basedir"/binds)" ]; then
    for f in $basedir/binds/* ;do
        . "$f"
    done
fi

command+=" -w /data/data/com.termux/files/home/"
command+=" /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/env -i"
command+=" HOME=/data/data/com.termux/files/home"
command+=" PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/applets"
command+=" TERM=$TERM"
command+=" ANDROID_DATA=/data"
command+=" ANDROID_ROOT=/system"
command+=" EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/sdcard"
command+=" LANG=$LANG"
command+=" LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib"
command+=" PREFIX=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr"
command+=" TMPDIR=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp"
com="$@"

if [ -z "$com" ];then
    eval "exec $command login"
else
    eval "exec $command login -c "$com""
fi
```

Error

```
./start.sh: line 39: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./start.sh: line 41: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Every double quotes are closed why it keeps throwing error
Tried running through sh instead of bash but still errors

also it shows erros on command+=" -b /system" about closing double quotes
can anyone explain?

Comment: Check your script with shellcheck.

Answer (score 2):

Recheck string:

```
eval "exec $command login -c "$com""
```

You have to escape double quotes in shell.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/how-to-escape-quotes-in-shell

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `eval`. Use arrays to store the *arguments* for the command.

```
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash
basedir=$(dirname "$0")

#unset LD_PRELOAD in case termux-exec is installed. If termux-exec is also installed inside the jail it will set again.
unset LD_PRELOAD

command="proot"
command_args=( 
  -r "$basedir/termux-fs"
  -b /system
  # etc
)

command_args+=(-b /property_contexts)

shopt -s nullglob
for f in "$basedir"/binds/*; do . "$f"; done

command_args+=(
  -w /data/data/com.termux/files/home/
  /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/env -i
  HOME=/data/data/com.termux/files/home  
  PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/applets
  "TERM=$TERM"
  # etc
  login
)
    
if (( $# == 0 )); then
  command_args+=( -c "$@" )
fi

exec "$command" "${command_args[@]}"
```